# PyCall Build Error and conda.core.link Error in Julia

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

I am new to Julia and want to run a script in Julia. The script needs to install PyPlot package, so I type Pkg.add("PyPlot") to add it. However, after downloading and updating some packages the following error will appears:

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\seabd4.julia\v0.6\Conda\deps\usr\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\seabd4.julia\v0.6\Conda\deps\usr\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.

=====================[ BUILD ERRORS ]==============================

WARNING: PyCall had build errors.

- packages with build errors remain installed in C:\Users\seabd4.julia\v0.6
- build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("PyCall")`
- build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

====================================================================

So, I tried to type `conda clean --packages` but an error appeared again

ERROR: syntax: extra token "clean" after end of expression

Would you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python that is built into Julia. Using an external Python is always possible but more pain ;-)

```
using Pkg
ENV["PYTHON"]=""
Pkg.build("PyCall")
Pkg.build("Conda")
Pkg.add("PyPlot") # or Pkg.build("PyPlot") depending when it failed
```

Comment: Thank you Przemyslaw, I tried out your suggestion but the same error is still persisting!

Comment: Now I noted that you have for some unkwon reason the path `C:\Users\seabd4.julia\v0.6` It is missing a slash - should be `C:\Users\seabd4\.julia\v0.6`. Additionally do you run Julia 0.6? this is not supported any more (and maybe something missinstalled on your machine). What about trying 1.6 or 1.7 instead?

Comment: I might have mistakingly delete the slash in the path when editing my question; the path is correct.  Yes, I am using Julia 0.6 because I want to run a script which is written for 0.6 and does not work with newer distributions. I have tried different older versions but new errors had came up!